# Referring to a range using variables (and filling down)

Tags: vba, excel, range

I basically want to check whether two columns have the same number of rows populated and if they don't then I would like to copy or fill down the last value in the shorter column until the columns are the same length.

Here are some of my attempts:

`LastP_iceRef` is the shorter column (if they are different lengths) and `LastWriterRow` is the longer of the two columns (where they differ - `LastP_iceRef` and `LastWriterRow` could be the same but I think I have code to take care of that.

`J` is  the column that `LastP_iceRef` comes from. I might be muddling up this column `J` and a variable `J` I have used for something else.

This doesn't work

```
Range("J" & (lastP_iceRef + 1) & " :  J" & LastWriterRow) = Sheets("Sorted data").Cells("J" & lastP_iceRef)`
```

and neither neither does:

```
Range(cells(lastP_iceRef + 1) ,"J" ),cells(LastWriterRow,"J") = Sheets("Sorted data").Cells("J" & lastP_iceRef)`
```

Is it bad practice to use letters as variable names? I often so for i=1 to x etc but it is a bit confusing to me in terms of excel column labels.

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine to use `"J"` in a `.Cells` call to specify column, generally I prefer it. Assuming you have the location right, it looks like your second one just has a misplaced parenthesis: `Range(cells(lastP_iceRef + 1) ,"J" ),cells(LastWriterRow,"J")` should be `Range(cells(lastP_iceRef + 1 ,"J" ),cells(LastWriterRow,"J"))`

Comment: "muddling up column `J` and variable `J`" is the _perfect_ example of why using good naming conventions is important. Rename variable `J` to indicate what it represents (`RowCount`, `ColumnLength`, `IceCreamTemperature`, whatever it may be), and it will become very obvious if you're using the variable when you mean to use the column (and vice-versa). After you've done that, if you still don't see where your error is, post your entire `Sub` and another set of eyes will most likely see your error.

Comment: Also, not sure if this was a typo, but you said "`LastP_iceRef` is the shorter column" and "`LastWriterRow` is the longer", but you use these variables as if they're the numbers of the last filled row for the corresponding columns (which would explain the errors if those variables are entire columns instead of a long)

Comment: Thanks Marcucciboy2 - I still couldn't make this work.

Comment: Mistella -  I did mean the numbers of the last filled rows - I was just trying to show which number was the larger of the two - I guess that's irrelevant - the code shouldn't fall over whichever way around they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
For i = lastP_iceRef + 1 To LastWriterRow
    Cells(i, 10).Value = Sheets("Sorted data").Cells(i-1, 10).Value
Next i
```

Thank you! This works.